# Trying to find the distance (Euclidean) between two nodes using networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

Any suggestions for as to how I can calculate the Euclidean distance between two nodes in a graph? Working with this graph:

```
nodes = [('B','D'), ('D','E'), ('D','A'), ('E','A'), ('E','C'), ('A','C')]
graph = nx.Graph(nodes)
nx.draw(graph, node_color = 'red', with_labels = True)
```

I have tried using

```
nx.shortest_path(graph, source, target)
```

Using nx.shortest_path() gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I know about Dijkstra's algorithm but I just want to calculate the Euclidean distance. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Euclidean distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to calculate the shortest distance like so:

```
dist = nx.shortest_path(graph, 'A', 'B')
```

the length of dist gives you the number of steps between nodes A and B:

```
len(dist)

# returns 3
```

Calcluating the Euclidean distance would require that the nodes have some sort of
coordinates associated with them.

e.g. stored in an attribute `coords`:

```
# adding coordinates:
for n in graph.nodes:
    graph.nodes[n]['coords'] = np.random.rand(2)
    
def get_euclidean_distance(graph, source, dest):
    x1, y1 = graph.nodes[source]['coords']
    x2, y2 = graph.nodes[dest]['coords']
    
    return np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2) 


get_euclidean_distance(graph, 'A', 'B')

# out 0.14540849196243125
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! ```len(dist)```  and associating coordinates with nodes was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the attribute 'coords', what I found:

```
graph.nodes[56407653]
{'y': 33.5077195, 'x': -86.8048775, 'street_count': 4}
```

So the function may change to:

```
def get_euclidean_distance(source, dest):
    x1, y1 = graph.nodes[source]['x'], graph.nodes[source]['y']
    x2, y2 = graph.nodes[dest]['x'], graph.nodes[dest]['y']
    
    return np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
```